# Importing from models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is the structure of my project:

```
onlineVersion/  crawler.py  conf.txt

./onlineVersion:
onlineVersion/  URLService/  links.db  manage.py

./onlineVersion/onlineVersion:
settings.pyc  urls.pyc  wsgi.pyc      __init__.py
settings.py   urls.py   __init__.pyc  wsgi.py

./onlineVersion/URLService:
serializers.pyc  models.py       views.pyc  __init__.pyc  tests.py
models.pyc       serializers.py  views.py   __init__.py
```

In the file crawler.py I try to import from the models.py file in the folder URLService using this command:

```
from onlineVersion.URLService.models import *
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named onlineVersion.URLService.models
```

Anyone has an idea how I get rid of this error message? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should put a `__init__.py` file in the ./onlineVersion dir.

Comment: confirmed. to quote the docs: "The \_\_init\_\_.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path."